# Unknown Text Shadow (Highcharts)

Tags: css, highcharts

I have a text shadow forming over the text of my chart area, despite my declarations to remove all shadows from both plot options and the graph area. Any help would be hugely appreciated because I'm losing my shit going over this code.

```
shadow:false
```

I've included that in both the chart theme files under the charts subcategory, along with the chart itself. Where is this shadow coming from?!

http://jsfiddle.net/r30zo8eL/

Comment: the shadow property is at the series level, and applies to the plotted graphic.  The textShadow property of the datalabels.style element is what you need to affect the text of the datalabel. Ref: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.style

Comment: Remove datalabels options from theme, then will work: http://jsfiddle.net/r30zo8eL/2/

Answer (score 4):

here you go!

```
plotOptions: {
pie: {
  allowPointSelect: true,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
      style: {
          textShadow: false, 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

edit for a bit of clarity:
I don't know much about HighCharts but it does seem that "shadow" and "textShadow" work independently of eachother

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts is setting the shadow automatically because your text is too light and is against a white background.
Change that and it will work ok

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
   dataLabels: {
    color: '#808080'
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

So all the css styles are being applied through javascript and that's always a nightmare. Would be better if you refactored it to separated them. But anyways I inspected the element  of the text and the tag they are in are `tspan` tags.
So applied this to CSS

`tspan {
  text-shadow: none;
}`
And VOILA! Shadow Gone! :-)